# What kind of encryption is used by IBM graph? Both for encryption at rest and encryption at transit? LUKS, SSL or others?

Tags: ssl, encryption, graph, ibm-graph, luks

I am doing some research on IBM graph and couldn't find the type of encryption used at both rest and transit. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Graph's client-facing APIs are only available via HTTPS w/ modern TLS versions. On the backend, data at rest is encrypted via LUKS, and data in motion is encrypted via TLS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin. It seems that there is limited documentation for technical details on IBM graph. Would you happen to know if they implement any user authentication (Kerberos and Active Directory Integration)? Also, can we write stored procedures for IBM graph?

Comment: IBM Graph supports HTTP Basic Authentication and a token-based session implementation. Regarding stored procedures:: TinkerPop/Gremlin does not support a notion of stored procedures.